# Cplex C++ out of memory error

Tags: c++, memory, cplex

I am doing some optimization with C++ and cplex and I keep getting an out of memory error despite having a significant amount of memory available.

I called the function

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::WorkMem, 7000);
```

Which should allocate more than enough memory for the program but it never seems to use it all. My OS is Windows 7 64 bit. I read somewhere that 32 bit systems limit the amount of memory GAMS can use so that shouldn't be a problem. But I did install the 32 bit version of cplex. Could this be the problem? I also made it run single threaded because I heard that it saved memory.

Comment: Asking for 7000 megabytes doesn't make much sense in a 32-bit process, you can never get more than ~2000.  Also see http://www.lkn.ei.tum.de/arbeiten/faq/man/ILOG/CPLEX/cplex75/doc/usermanccpp/html/solveMIP32.html

Comment: 32-bit processes certainly won't be able to access more than 4 GB of memory.  Single threaded will only save you a small amount of memory and won't help you here.  At what point do you get the out-of-memory error?  It's likely that the model instance itself is too big to fit into 32-bit address space.

Comment: I just watched it is it ran.  And it ran out at 1,912 megabytes.  So looks like a 32-bit problem.  I downloaded the 64 bit version but then I realized that the graphics library I am using, SFML, was compiled for 32-bit and I don't want to download the compile the binaries right now. 

I heard there are some modes I can run in to reduce memory costs.  What are they?  Right now the problem I am running probably requires only 1/4th the memory I will need for full scale.  So I may run into memory issues ever after moving to 64-bit.